# Core data object get saved, but doesn't show up in table until I pop to related object table and then come forward

Tags: ios, core-data, uinavigationcontroller, swift3, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have three view controllers embedded in a navigation controller.

[image: storyboard]

The first view controller is a list of tests, which use fetchedResultsController to populate the table.

The second view controller is a detail view controller, which allows adding a new test, editing it's detail, saving the new test or adding Questions to the test.  It also includes a table of questions, which is also populated with a fetchedResultsController.

[image: TestDetailsVC view]
[image: Add Question button triggers the save]

The problem I have is that when I have an existing Test which is saved, then when I go to add on questions, they correctly populate the table when I pop back to the TestDetailsVC, however, if I'm adding a new test, and then adding new questions to it, the test saves to core data, then in the QuestionDetailsVC questions also save to core data.  However, when I pop back to the TestDetailsVC, the new questions don't populate the table.  However, when I navigate back to the TestListVC and then go forward, the questions then populate the table correctly.  I'm trying to get the questions to populate the table the first time I pop back to the table.  Shouldn't the table re-fetche this data when the view loads, and the table work correctly when I navigate back since these objects are saved in core data?  Why does it work correctly with a previously saved test object, but not work with a newly saved test object?

My code for saving the new test in the TestDetailsVC is:

```
//if we tap on a row, then we select that question to edit
//if a question is selected, we will pass that information over to
//the question editor view so it can be edited    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //make sure there is at least one question
    //objs = means object selected
    if let objs = controller.fetchedObjects, objs.count > 0 {
        //if there is, keep track of the test which is selected
        let question = objs[indexPath.row]
        //pass along that test to the editor to be edited
        //the sender is the selected test at that particular row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditQuestionSegue", sender: question)
    }
}


//we need to get ready to do the segue before we call it
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        switch identifier {
        case "EditQuestionSegue":
            //find the question needing to be edited
            //pass this along to the question editing view controller
            if let destination = segue.destination as? QuestionDetailsVC {
            if let question = sender as? Question {
                destination.questionToEdit = question
                //pass along the test that the question is
                //related to also
                if let test = testToEdit {
                    destination.testToEdit = test
                    }
                }
            }
        case "AddNewQuestionSegue":
            //if no test to edit got passed in, it means
            //we're now editing a new test
            //once we type in the test title, then we have to
            //make sure the test has been saved if it's new test
            //before we go on to edit questions
            if testToEdit == nil {

                saveTestBeforeAddingQuestion()
                //make sure we set up as if new
                //before we start adding questions
                //these are called in the view did load
            }
            if let destination = segue.destination as? QuestionDetailsVC {
                if let test = testToEdit {
                    destination.testToEdit = test
                }
            }
        default:
            print("no segue this time")
        }
    }
}

func saveTestBeforeAddingQuestion() {

    var test: Test!


    //if there's not a passed in value into the testToEdit core data
    //object test entity, then we're going to edit as if new
    if testToEdit == nil {
        //then instantiate a new test object ready to be written to
        test = Test(context: context)
    } else {
        test = testToEdit
    }

    if let title = titleTextField.text {
        test.title = title
    }


    if let abrevTitle = abrevTitleTextField.text {
        test.abrevTitle = abrevTitle
    }
    if let author = authorTextField {
        test.author = author.text
    }
    if let publisher = publisherTextField {
        test.publisher = publisher.text
    }


     ad.saveContext()
    //since we have now saved a new test
    //let's put that test into our testToEdit variable
    //so we can pass it along to the next view controller
    //during our segue
     if let newTestCreated = test {
        testToEdit = newTestCreated
    }
}
```

My code for saving the new question is:

```
   @IBAction func savePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

          var question: Question!

        //if there's not a passed in value into the questionToEdit core data
        //object test entity, then we're going to edit as if new
        if questionToEdit == nil {
            //then instantiate a new test object ready to be written to
            question = Question(context: context)
        } else {
            question = questionToEdit
        }

        //make sure to relate the question added to the testToEdit test
        question.test = self.testToEdit

        //if there is something in the sentence text field
        //then assign that value to the question.sentence attribute
        //of the sentence entity in our core data context
        if let sentence = questionSentenceTextField.text {
            question.sentence = sentence
        }
        if let identifier = questionIdentifierTextField.text {
            question.identifier = identifier
        }
        if let displayOrder = questionDisplayOrderTextField.text {
            question.displayOrder = Int(displayOrder) as NSNumber?
        }

        // save the context
        ad.saveContext()

        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent days trying to get the question table to load, but finally discovered that it wasn't loading back up because when I pop back to the view controller it doesn't automatically reload the table with the fetchedResultsController.  So I had to place a call to refetch the data in the viewWillAppear method and then reload the tableView:

(TestDetailsVC)

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        guard testToEdit != nil else {return}
        attempFetch()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```